# Windows 7 Pro can't change background

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Up until yesterday I could change my desktop background as much as I want. Now I can only set it to a solid color, or to an image from internet explorer. I tried going to my theme folder as described [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_10025846_remove-transcoded-wallpaper.html), and I don't have access to the accessibility or control panels. Can anyone suggest another method to fix this?

Comment: You don't have access to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization`?

Comment: @Michael Bell: See if one of these methods help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2504610/en-us

Comment: I can access Personalization through right-click, but the control panel itself is disabled. The admin has setup some odd group policies

Answer (score 1):

These generally happens when Windows is not genuine. Please make sure its genuine.

Comment: It is genuine. This is my school computer

Comment: I suppose I will do that. It's weird that it just stopped working though

Comment: @MichaelBell If it is your school's computer then bring it to them. They may have enabled GPO to block some customization. Or, to play off the answer above sometimes if there is a licensing server it needs to talk back to stay validated ***edited***